# How to handle to get right host and port in JAVA if test is run against different setup

Tags: java, if-statement, port, host

If I run tests against single node instance, test should pick managed server host and port.Else if I run tests against 2 node instance,  test should pick load balancer host and port.

Please help how this can be achieved?

My below code failed when single node instance is detected as load balancer host and port are not available in json file. It is passed in 2 node as load balancer details are available in json file.

Important note:
    json file is different for single node and 2 node. As load balancer details are not required for single node, that part is not available in single node json file.

If single node -> pick managed server host and port
    else
    If 2 node -> pick load balancer host and port

```
TestConfig testConfig = TestConfig.load();

if (testConfig.getHosts().getLoadBalancer().getHost().equals("qa_lbr")) {
    LBR_HOST = testConfig.getHosts().getLoadBalancer().getHost();
    System.out.println("Running tests against LBR instance - " + LBR_HOST);

    LBR_PORT = testConfig.getHosts().getLoadBalancer().getPort();
    System.out.println("Running tests against LBR port - " + LBR_PORT);
    System.setProperty("biee.url.va", "http://" + LBR_HOST + ":" + LBR_PORT + "/dv/ui");
    url = "http://" + LBR_HOST + ":" + LBR_PORT + "/analytics";
    System.out.println("URL is:" + url);
} else {
    List<Host> managedHost = testConfig.getHosts().getManagedServers();
    BI_HOST = managedHost.get(0).getHost();
    System.out.println("Running tests against managed server instance - " + BI_HOST);
    BI_PORT = managedHost.get(0).getPort();
    System.out.println("Running tests against managed server port - " + BI_PORT);
    System.setProperty("biee.url.va", "http://" + BI_HOST + ":" + BI_PORT + "/dv/ui");
    url = "http://" + BI_HOST + ":" + BI_PORT + "/analytics";
    System.out.println("URL is:" + url);
}
```

Comment: How do you find the no. of nodes - what's the condition that needs to be checked tom make a decision? It seems to me, here, that you're checking whether the `host` is configured as "qa_lbr"?

Comment: Condition to check is: Which node is used currently? I knew which node is used but not sure how to handle it in test. Yes in my current code am checking if host is configured as "qa_lbr" but that does not work for single node. My current code works only for 2 node.